# Is it possible to inject an instance method delegate from a non-singleton component with Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, oop, functional-programming, castle-windsor

**Background:** Given interface, implementation, and consumer

```
public interface IDoer {
    int DoIt(string arg);
}

public class LengthDoer : IDoer { 
    int _internalState;
    public LengthDoer(IDependency dep) { _internalState = dep.GetInitialValue(); }
    public int DoIt(string arg) { 
        _internalState++;
        return arg.Length;
    }
}

public class HighLevelFeature {
    public HighLevelFeature(IDoer doer) { /* .. */ }
}
```

then it is straightforward to configure Windsor to inject `Doer` into `HighLevelFeature` upon construction, where `LengthDoer` has a `PerWebRequest` lifestyle.

**Problem:** However, if the design were to change to

```
public delegate int DoItFunc(string arg);

// class LengthDoer remains the same, without the IDoer inheritance declaration

public class HighLevelFeature {
    public HighLevelFeature(DoItFunc doer) { /* .. */ }
}
```

then is it possible to configure Windsor to inject `LengthDoer.DoIt` as an instance method delegate where `LengthDoer` has `PerWebRequest` lifestyle, *such that Windsor can track and Release LengthDoer instances*? In other words, Windsor would mimic:

```
// At the beginning of the request
{
    _doer = Resolve<LengthDoer>();
    return _hlf = new HighLevelFeature(doer.DoIt);
}

// At the end of the request
{
    Release(_doer);
    Release(_hlf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoItFunc` delegate can be registered using `UsingFactoryMethod`:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IDoer>().ImplementedBy<LengthDoer>());
container.Register(Component.For<DoItFunc>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel =>
        {
            return new DoItFunc(kernel.Resolve<IDoer>().DoIt);
        }));
```

Comment: Wow! The surprising and unexpected thing about this is that Windsor tracks the resolutions within the factory method. In other words, if `LengthDoer` implements `IDisposable`, then when you `Resolve`+`Release` a `DoItFunc`, Windsor will call `Dispose` on the bound `LengthDoer` instance. This is unexpected because Krzysztof Koźmic wrote that you must release all components resolved in a factory method. http://kozmic.net/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/ Thanks.